# To avoid type checking is it okay to call ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object) by passing String argument

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Is it bad if I use `String ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object value)` when my value object can either be a `String` or an object of `MyClass` (containing `JsonNode`). I have a method which uses generics and returns either `String` or `MyClass` object which I want to serialize to String and want to avoid the type check.

Essentially want to know that calling `String ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(Object)` by passing `String` argument is bad?

I am using `jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar` and referring to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` and 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyClass {
  private String id;
  private JsonNode data;

  @JsonProperty("data")
  public JsonNode getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(JsonNode data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @JsonProperty("id")
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

I am currently doing this and want to avoid it:

```
T value = someMethod();
if (value instanceof String) {
  valueString = (String) value;
} else {
  valueString = mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
}
```

where T can either be `String` or `MyClass`.

Comment: What's your alternative? What are you comparing? What are your doubts?

Comment: Updated the alternative in the question. My double is if I simply call `mapper.writeValueAsString(value)` without checking type, is it bad in anyway like performance or practice wise?

Comment: Does `value` already contain JSON content if it's a `String`?

Comment: T can either be `String` or `MyClass`. I have mentioned `MyClass` declaration in my question.

Comment: If it's a `String`, is its content JSON? What does it contain?

Comment: I may or may not be JSON.

Comment: If it's not, then you have to use `writeValueAsString`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212990/discussion-between-learner-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: Sotirios, Sorry, I didn't quite follow you.
when you say "you have to use writeValueAsString" what does that mean. If it is a simple string such as "My name is John" why do I have to use "writeValueAsString"
My question was essentially this: 
If for simple String value we call `mapper.writeValueAsString("My name is John" )` is there an issue?

Comment: `My name is John` is not valid JSON. Presumably, you're trying to produce JSON. So you would need to call `writeValueAsString` on it to generate `"My name is John"` which **is** valid JSON. But if your `value` was already JSON, then `writeValueAsString` would double encode it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I don't want to generate JSON from "My Name is John". I want to have the same String returned as is. All I want to do is avoid the type check I am doing with `instanceof` operator thus always call `writeValueAsString` so that if it's String it returns the same and if it's `JSON` object it returns  json String.

Comment: Your goal (its purpose) is very unclear to me. `writeValueAsString` will transform the String into a different String (its JSON serialization). If you don't want that, don't use it. Regardless, `instanceof` is cheap.

Comment: that's why I wanted to avoid `instaceof` and thought of this solution, what is a better alternative to this then?